# Como abro automaticamente un link de spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

Estoy haciendo un programa que envia automaticamente ciertos archivos que hay en google drive y todo con la informacion suministrada desde un formulario de google pero quiero que el link del archivo se abra de forma automatica en cuanto se envie el formulario y por eso guardo el link en la hoja de calculo

El link se guarda en la hoja de calculo que automaticamente crea forms de google y desde ahi quiero que este se presione automaticamente ya que fue la opcion que mejor va con el tipo de programa que estoy haciendo

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Contrario a lo que se puede hacer con formularios web realizados con HTML/CSS/JavaScript con los formularios de Google no es posible.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.